# How to render text (in svg) if text font size is smaller than 1

Tags: svg

Well, I have a SVG with a viewbox like this

```
viewbox="-20.121819 -110.123123 0.237889 0.258823"
```

I need to render text inside, but it's not rendering, I guess the minimum font size is 1, so, is this possible without changing viewbox attribute in my SVG?

Ty in advance.

Comment: Please try this: `<svg viewbox="-20.121819 -110.123123 0.237889 0.258823">
  <text x="-20" y="-110" font-size=".1" fill="black">?</text>
</svg>` It works. The problem may be in your code. Please edit your question and add your code. Also please read [The Limits of Numbers in SVG](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch08-precision.html)

Comment: It's not really going to work for you. Change the viewBox.

Comment: I'm trying this in an ionic app, maybe the webview can't calculate this properly? I will try this later and also update my question if needed. If something change I will add another comment, ty for the info :)